# How do I find on demand graphic designers in the NYC area with out using an agency?

Tags: print-design, illustration, hiring

Looking for quality, on demand designs with varying skills for on demand for print design work is nearly impossible. 
Does anyone have a process of how they interview freelancers?
How do you validate their skills?

Comment: Upwork.com.......